# Showing user uploaded photos on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is it possible to show photos uploaded by user to my site on google maps?

I found panoramio which is dying in june 15, which works with it's on photo store.

Basically once a user uploads a photo to my web app, i want to show that on google maps. I know users locations.

Is there an API, js or an easy way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GroundOverlay

Comment: No i didnt know that. Will give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. You should be probably have a background service that automatically creates a thumbnail and stores the url in your database. So, you pass the thumbnail url, the fullImageUrl and the coordinates of the place into the following function. Here the thumbnail is used as the marker image or icon and you can give it any size you want.

```
    function CreateMarker(thumbnailUrl, coords, fullImageUrl)
    {   
        // marker icon creation   
        imageIcon = {
            url: thumbnailUrl,
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(10, 10); // adjust as needed
        };

        // marker creation
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: coords,
            icon: imageIcon,
            map: map //your map object
        });

        // create info window
        var contentString = '<div class="fullImage">' + 
           '<img src=fullImageUrl /></div>'; // style with css

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    }
```

Hope it helps.